# Laravel File::allfiles() InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to retrieve the list of files in a given directory `(C:/path/to/folder/)` using the `File::allFiles()` method. This works well on my localhost.

Problem is when I upload and execute it on my remote server it returns

`InvalidArgumentException in Finder.php line 546: 
The "C:/path/to/folder" directory does not exist.`

Is there a different approach to this or are there configurations that need to be set for this to work?

Comment: You don't have `C:/path/to/folder/` on remote server. You should use something like `/path/to/folder` without using full path name. If you can provide your Controller location and your folder location then i can tell you proper path. Btw, you should have your folder inside Laravel project

Comment: I'm trying to access a folder outside of my laravel project. The directory path is supplied by the end user.

Comment: If user defines you path from his computer then you can't load file like that. Use something like `file_get_contents(PATH_OF_FOLDER);`

Comment: `file_get_contents(PATH_OF_FOLDER): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: Have you replaced `PATH_OF_FOLDER` with proper path like `C:/path/to/folder/` ? So your code should look like `file_get_contents("C:/path/to/folder");`

Comment: yes i did replace it.

Comment: Do you have that folder on your computer (client) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134590/discussion-between-raz-and-kukec).

Answer (score 0):

Use [SCANDIR](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to list all files in your directory

```
$files = scandir("C:/path/to/folder/");
```